# Are variables saved when exporting a Tensorflow Estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

Are the values of the variables (such as the Batch Normalization `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`) saved when the Estimator is exported? (e.g. with a BestExporter)

This is currently how I export the model:

```py
best_exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
        name=best_model_path,
        serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
        exports_to_keep=1)
exporter = [best_exporter]

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(...)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(...,
    exporters=exporter)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(ben_classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

At training time, I am adding the update operations for the BatchNormalization to the training operation

```py
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=L_RATE)
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_ops = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_ops)
```

Restoring with a `tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model` does not allow checking the values of the variables. 
So, my question is, is there a way to check it? And if so, how is it possible to save these BN variables at exporting time?

My performance at inference time is much worse from the one at training and evaluation time. I discarded the overfitting option because it's a very simple network and plus, performing the predictions directly using the estimator model at the end of the training (or generally the last one) would result in better performance than the best model.

Comment: You will find them in the checkpoints generated during training.

Comment: @YoloSwaggins Yes, but is there a way to save them in the exported model? Or should I load them somehow from the training checkpoints?

Comment: I must have missed something because I don't understand why you want them in the savedmodel, to inspect the values a checkpoint is enough. Do you intend to perform some kind of manipulation of the activations at inference time using those values?

Comment: If you just wish to look at the values take a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#inspect_variables_in_a_checkpoint). If you have an estimator instance just use [`estimator.latest_checkpoint()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#latest_checkpoint) for the checkpoint name.

Comment: If you wish to look at the values stored in the savedmodel load it into a `tf.Session` then call `tf.global_variables()`. The only thing that should be here from the batch normalization layers are the `gamma` and `beta` variables aka scale and shift.

Comment: @YoloSwaggins My goal is to make sure that the BatchNormalization at inference time, uses the same moving variables (mean and variance) that I have at training time. Your comment made me discover the `tf.saved_model.loader.load` API, which allows doing what you said.. `tf.global_variables()` contains all the variables of the model, including BN moving_variance/mean

Comment: Great that worked out for you but if the moving variance and mean are in the inference savedmodel it means that the batch norm layer didn't have it's `training` flag set correctly at export time.